# I have a dataframe which consists of customer_name, sell_date, transaction_id. I want to calculate total number of transaction in each year

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSBQF.png)
I want my output to be in format below

```
customer_name   #transactions_inyr1   #transactions_inyr2
```

Please help me with code

I tried

```
df['year']= df["Sell_Date"].dt.year
df.groupby(["year","Customer-name"])["Trans_Num"].agg('count')
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible input, the expected output and explain how your current code fails. Looks like you just want `df.groupby(["year","Customer-name"])["Trans_Num"].agg('count').unstack('year')`

Comment: can you provide input code and desired output?